# apache solr multi word wild card search not working

Tags: solr

We are using apache solr with php.

There is a problem in multi word  wild card searching.

We want to search "project manage*" which can list possible results like project manager, project management etc. However, it is not working whenever there are two words in wild card searching

For example "projectmanage*" is working whereas "proejct manage*" is not working. We also tried by escaping the space but it is not working either..

we tried 
\ before space
ReversedWildcardFilterFactory
NGramTokenizerFactory etc

Please forward your valuable feedbacks

Comment: I have zero experience with it, but it seems that https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/other-parsers.html#complex-phrase-query-parser was build for this exact purpose

Comment: Can you post your relevant portion of solr schema ? like what is the field type of that  and what tokenizer are you using.

Comment: field type used is text_general, NGramTokenizer